# Error while adding Mysqli extension to PHP in windows

Tags: php, mysql, apache, mysqli

I have uncommented the extension and set the appropriate directory in php.in file. Restarted the Apache server.

```
**extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll;
```

On windows:

```
 extension_dir =  C:\php\ext**
```

But, still facing this issue on error on windows while connecting to mysql database using mysqli.

Fatal error:

```
Call to undefined function mysqli_connect().
```

Comment: be careful, you could be editing the wrong php.ini use `phpinfo()` to check for installs

Answer (score 0):

1. Restore everything like it should be. Use only PHP's DLL files.
2. Uncomment both mysql and mysqli lines in php.ini.
3. Copy libmysql.dll from your PHP folder and paste it into your Apache
   /bin folder while leaving the original copy in the PHP folder.

restart apache and see if that works.

Comment: I followed the same kind of answer in some other post. There will be no libmysql.dll file in PHP 5.* versions.